# CSS Positioning assistance on navigation content slider

Tags: html, css, positioning

I'm having problems aligning two elements. I wish to align the pagination in the middle of the navigational arrows for my two mini content sliders.

Design example of what I require:

http://www.garyrevell.co.uk/student-i/PastedGraphic-8.png

The current WIP in progress live site - http://www.garyrevell.co.uk/student-i/index.html

The CSS

```
#slider1 { height: 1%; overflow:hidden; padding: 0 0 0 0;   }

#slider1 .viewport { float: left; width: 240px; min-height: 190px; overflow: hidden; position: relative; }

#slider1 .buttons { background:url("../images/buttons.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; display: inline-block;  background-position: 0 -38px; text-indent: -999em; float: left; width: 39px; height: 24px; overflow: hidden; position: relative;  }

#slider1 .previous { background-position: 0 0; margin-left:5px;  }
#slider1 .next { background-position: 0 0; left: 130px }
#slider1 .disable { visibility: hidden; }

#slider1 .overview { list-style: none; position: absolute; padding: 0; margin: 0; width: 240px; left: 0 top: 0; }
#slider1 .overview li{ float: left; margin: 0 20px 0 0; padding: 1px; width: 230px;}

    /* Tiny Carousel - Slider Bullets */

#slider1 .pager, #slider2 .pager { overflow:hidden; list-style: none; clear: top; margin: 0 0 0 45px; }

/*Normal Style*/

#slider1 .pager li, #slider2 .pager li{ float: left;  display: block; 

}

#slider1 .pager a, #slider2 .pager a { width: 15px;
height: 12px;
width: 12px;
background:url(../images/bullet-norm.png); background-position: left top; background-repeat:no-repeat;
float: left;
text-indent: -4000px;
position: relative;
margin-left: 3px;
color: transparent;
display:inline-block;
cursor: pointer;



}

#slider1 .pager a:hover{
    background-position: 0 50%;

}


#slider1 .pager .active {
    color: #fff; background-image:  url(../images/bullet-selected.png); } /*CURRENT IMAGE HERE*/
    #slider1 .overview { list-style: none; position:    absolute; width: 240px; left: 0 top: 0; }

    #slider1 .overview li{ float: left; margin: 0 20px 0 0;  width: 236px;


}



    a.pagenum {margin-top: 12px;}



    ul{border:0; margin:0; padding:0;}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thankyou everyone for all you're help. You guys are awesome! problem solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set

```
ul.pager{
     margin: 0 auto; 
     display: table; (ife the first line above alone did not work...)
}
```

Place this code after any of your other .pager referenced code
Also, remove any padding on the .pager class

Answer (score 0):

Please update your `css` with mine `css` you will achieve your desired result :-

**CSS**

```
#slider1 .pager, #slider2 .pager {
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0 0 0 45px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    top: -23px;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou looks brilliant now. The "next" arrow is not working is there something I have to take out in the css now?

Answer (score 0):

Float `left` & `right` respectively the navigational arrows and remove `left: 130px;` from the second one.

Set equal `left` & `right` margin on `ul.pager`, set `text-align: center` on it and give its `li` `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

You can even align the pagination to be centered

CSS:

```
.pager-wrapper{
    padding: 5px; 
    height: 23px;
    width: something;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
a {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 4px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1px;
}
a:hover {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}
.selected {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="pager-wrapper" >
<a class="selected" href="#">1</a><a href="#">2</a><a href="#n">3</a><a href="#">4</a>
</div>
```